# Why is the 'Favorite' count so low in the Stack Overflow data?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, data-dump, posts

In the Stack Overflow database, there is a column called "favorite count". I have found that favorite count indicates users find the question interesting or save it for later review.

I have the bulk of Stack Overflow posts (post title only), but I got very minimal number of favorite counts. For example, in 50,000 posts (Stack Overflow questions) only six questions (post titles) have a favorite count. The rest of them have "null" or "0".
Why is my favorite count so low?

Is there any other column to get the favorite count?
Does the favorite count column contain the number of users who bookmarked those posts?

Comment: Is this about the data dumps or SEDE? Here's the [answer for SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383382/323179), but the root cause is the same.

Comment: I have read the details but I am still unclear that Does favourite count column contains number of users who bookmarked that posts?

Comment: No, everything was converted to Saves, which are private. If there are any numbers left over in the column in the database, they're mistakes, possibly from anomalies like the app (now very much dead) still being able to create favorites/bookmarks.